R executable missing after installing r-base-core WSL 2
I was having trouble with package dependencies in R, so I wanted to completely erase all traces of R and re install it. After insalling r-base-core, I can't find where the R executable lives so I can add it to my path and use R.
I first successfully removed all R stuff with the following:
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/*
sudo rm -rf ~/.R
sudo rm -rf ~/.RData
sudo rm -rf ~/.Rhistory
sudo apt-get purge r-base
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/R
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/R
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/R
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/R
sudo apt-get update

I then tried re installing R with the following:
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev r-recommended

the installation seemed successful. However when I try to get into R, it says the following:
Command 'R' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install r-base-core

but it was just installed. I tried finding all R executables or things named R with sudo find / -name R
and a very long list popped out, mostly in the following directories:
/var/snap/docker/common/
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/
/usr/share
/usr/lib/R
/usr/lib/R/library


I just want to wipe out R from my WSL 2 instance and start from scratch. What's going on? There are no bin folders that exist within /usr/lib/R, /usr/lib/R/library, and no R executable in /usr/local/bin.

What does dpkg -s r-base-core | head -4 say?  Mine says on line two 'Status: install ok installed' and for dpkg -S /usr/bin/R it correctly find the r-base-core package as source of the file.

Output of dpkg -s r-base-core | head -4 says the same thing as you, and dpkg -S /usr/bin/R prints out "r-base-core: /usr/bin/R". But there is no R executable when I actually go to that directory @AdaLovelace

Maybe your acts of randomly deleting files that the package manager things are still there confused matters.  sudo apt install r-base-core should set you straight.  Also consider sudo dpkg --purge r-base-core to really remove and "purge" the package.  You did something that really is not anticipated or recommend by forcefully removing files the system and package manager control so you may be in uncharted territory.
